# Web Interface for SSAS

Tags: sql, iis, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, windows-server-2008-r2

We have several SSAS cubes - we want these cubes to be accessible via HTTP on the local network so that they can be viewed over iPads.  Excel is our go-to utility for this, but since Excel is not available for iPad, it is not an option here.

Are there any other ways that I can display cubes on IIS and have iPad viewers be able to access them?

Comment: I'm to searching for SSAS WEB interface on all platforms. HTML5 probably would be the best solution.

Answer (score -1):

I beleive your information is out-of-date - SharePoint 2013 (Excel Web) supports Safari on iPad (Safari on iOS):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161353.aspx

Comment: @Justin : The question asked made no mention of cost, so your comments are OT.  Anyway they now offer SharePoint online for something like $7/user/month. You get what you pay for - Microsoft are clearly investing heavily in R&D to improve and broaden SharePoint. For this particular functionality I'm not aware of any serious alternatives.

Comment: Whoever downvoted should reconsider the original question or clearly state their reasons.